# Retornar apenas um determinado elemento da página atual com jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, formulário

Pessoal estou precisando pegar apenas um elemento da página atual retornado via AJAX. O elemento que preciso é o de **id="principal"**.

O máximo que eu consegui é pegar a página inteira, mas eu só queria esse elemento citado acima.

```
<form  id="sd_submit-job-form" class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2 style='color:blue'>Escolha o tipo de anúncio:</h2>          
    <select name="aaa" id="sd-valorSel" >
        <option value="-1">Selecionar...</option>           
        <option value="1">Achados & Perdidos</option>
        <option value="2">Anúncio de Imóveis</option>   
    </select>
    <br>
</form>
<br>    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$("#sd_submit-job-form").change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: this.action,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);   // retorna toda a página     
            var xxx = $(data).find("#principal");
            alert(xxx);     
            //$("#retorno").html(xxx);            
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Problema ao carregar a solicitação via Ajax.");
        }
    });
});     
</script>   

<div id="principal">Eu preciso que retorne apenas esse elemento.</div>
<div id="retorno"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se `#principal` for um elemento filho direto do `body` (parece ser o caso), use `.filter()`:

```
<body>
   <div id="principal"></div>
</body>

$(data).filter("#principal");
```

Caso contrário, use `.find()`:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <div id="principal"></div>
   </div>
</body>

$(data).find("#principal");
```

Isso porque `$(data)` irá retornar um *nodelist* e o `find` irá buscar dentro desses nós o elemento `#principal`. Se esse elemento for filho direto do body, ele será um nó principal, e o `find` não irá encontrá-lo.

Já o `filter` irá pegar direto o nó principal que casar com o seletor.

**[Documentação do .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Comment: O .filter não funcionou em meu script. Tem mais alguma ideia? Preciso muito resolver essa questão.

Comment: O filter mostrou o que no $(data)?

Comment: Retornou [object Object]. Apenas isso. E com .find acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: Está correto. O [object Object] é a div#principal. Ela é um objeto jQuery. Se vc quiser pegar o HTML dela: `xxx.html()`

Comment: Perfeito!! Funcionou!! Valeu pela força!!